# What controls accept all keyboard and mouse messages in uwp (button does not accept leftbuttondown)

Tags: uwp

I need a control that can accept all keyboard and mouse events.Or how do custom controls accept keyboard and mouse events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, almost all controls can receive events from the keyboard or mouse.

> button does not accept leftbuttondown

If you just listen to the `Button.Click` event, it can only determine whether the button is clicked. The triggering method can be the mouse or the finger etc. There is no left-right difference for the finger.

**You can listen for `PointerPressed` event**

```cs
private void Button_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Button);
    if (pointer.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        if (pointer.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, the events related to Pointer include `PointerEntered`, `PointerExited`, etc.

For keyboard events, you can listen for events like `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`.

Like this:

```cs
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

---

If you want to learn more, these documents may be helpful:

- [Mouse input events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/mouse-interactions#mouse-input-events)
- [Keyboard events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-events)

Comment: thank you。 I use addhandler()  to make button receive leftbuttondown.For custom controls, your methods are fine, too.